# Generating ul li nested tree structure

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

I have `Employee` Table. And in that table I've `reporting_to` field. It is parent child relationship. I want to show the nested `ul li` html tree in `JSP`.

Here is my mysql table.

[image]

I want something like

```
<ul>
<li>root
 <ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2
      <ul>
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

here are my 2 java functions

```
public ResultSet getSavedTree() throws SQLException{
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {   
             s = ds.createStatement();               

             rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM pep.employee_tree order by reporting_to;");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rs;

        }

    public ResultSet getPertiSavedTree(int sapCode) throws SQLException{
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {   
             s = ds.createStatement();           

             rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM pep.employee_tree WHERE reporting_to = "+sapCode+" order by reporting_to;");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rs;

        }
```

And here is my HTML

```
<ul  id="org" style="display:none">
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-hover-e ui-btn-up-e"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text" style="font-size:10px;">3214657890<br/>Root<br/>SAP<br/>SSE</span></span></a>
                <ul id="main_child_ul" class="children">


              <%
               ResultSet SavedEmployeesTree = empTree.getSavedTree();

               String children[];
               String sapCode="";
                while (SavedEmployeesTree.next()){
                    ResultSet SavedEmployeesTreeChild = empTree.getPertiSavedTree(Integer.parseInt(SavedEmployeesTree.getString("sap_code")));
                        while(SavedEmployeesTreeChild.next())
                        {
                            if(SavedEmployeesTree.getString("sap_code").equals(SavedEmployeesTreeChild.getString("reporting_to")))
                            {
                    %>

                            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-hover-b ui-btn-up-b"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text" style="font-size:10px;"><%=SavedEmployeesTreeChild.getString("sap_code")%></span></span></a>



            <%              }
                            else
                            {%>
                                <ul class="children">
                                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-hover-b ui-btn-up-b"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text" style="font-size:10px;"><%=SavedEmployeesTreeChild.getString("sap_code")%></span></span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            <%}
                        }
                } 

            %>
            </li>
               </ul>




            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: And where is your attempted solution?

Comment: I'm trying but not getting correct

Comment: @hallaji I posted my stupid solution.

Comment: you should learn about [core tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html), and don't use scriptlets.